# How to show a particular day with different color using Tapku library calendar

Tags: iphone, ipad, calendar, tapku

I have  been successfully implemented   Tapku  calendar , but  I want show a particular day with different color e.g. sunday occuring in every month again how I can show the dates b/w to different dates e.g. 01/01/2012 to 01/02/2012  with different color
thanks in advance ,